# After initiating Rails Server, command line disappears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

new to Ruby and Rails so forgive me if this is super simple but I'm working my way through the Hartl tutorial and everything was going OK until I initiated the following command in the first chapter: User-Name-Macbook-Pro:first_app username$ rails server

It did what it was supposed to do (provided server info and started) BUT after the command finished, the terminal didn't give me "User-Name-Macbook-Pro:first_app username$" to enter in any more commands. Instead, it's just a blank line now and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing the following, everything is working as it should:

```
rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-04-13 19:46:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-13 19:46:14] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
[2013-04-13 19:46:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=27467 port=3000
```

The command line will not returned unless you exit the server with ctrl-C or the application crashes

Comment: Ok I received all of that! The tutorial now wants me to configure some gits (ie "$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email your.email@example.com") and initialize the git ("$ git init") but I guess I'm not sure how to do that now that I don't have a proper command line... do I have to exit the server in order to continue with the git configurations?

Comment: Leave the server running, and either enter a new Terminal tab or a new Terminal window.

Comment: It is a problem if I exit the server, punch in more commands, then restart the server as opposed to leaving it on and using a new term tab/window?

Comment: You can exit if you want. But, I generally keep several tabs open at once. For example, a tab for the server (that way I can browse the app in development whenever I want while I'm working), one for tests with guard, and one for entering commands.

Comment: When I open a new tab, does the terminal know what I'm working on or do I have to change directories to my "first_app" folder? In other words, what do I have to do when I open a new tab so that both tabs are essentially in sync?

Comment: Well, if you're working on "first_app", then you always need to be in that directory. Depending on your bash (i.e. Terminal) settings or if you're running something else (I use something called zsh, for instance), it might automatically put you in your current directory, or it will be in the home directory. You'll know either way because to the left of the cursor you'll see the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

`rails server` initiates your server.  You can terminate this process with CTRL + C.  So see your rails app in action, go to `localhost:3000` in your preferred(Chrome of course) browser.

Comment: awesome - got it. Once I exit the server I can then get back to my commands and configure my gits. And of course... it has to be Chrome! ;)

Comment: great!  Be sure to +1/mark as answer if it answered your questions!